# Конструктор класса, с++

Tags: c++, конструктор

Здравствуйте, не могли бы вы мне объяснить в чем заключается моя ошибка(или не понимание) в данном коде.

У меня имеется класс дерево которое имеет у себя конструктор

```
AVL_Tree<Key, mapped_type, Compare>::AVL_Tree(std::string dir)
        {
            root = lastAction = nullptr;
            dirName = dir;
            count = 0;
            Key key=10;
            mapped_type value = 11;
            insert(std::make_pair(key, value));
        };
```

Узел дерева представляет собой структуру.

```
struct Tree_ 
        {
            Key key;
            std::string* addr;
            unsigned char height;
            Tree_* parent;
            Tree_* left;
            Tree_* right;
            Tree_(Key k, std::string* p) {
                key = k;
                addr = p;
                left = right = parent = 0;
                height = 1;
            }
}
```

при insert находится позиция узла по отношению к корню и вставляется новый обьект узла(думаю нету смысла показывать код insertа)
вставляю код таким образом

```
p = new Tree_(k.first,&dirName);
```

проблема в том что при создании экземпляра древа:

```
typedef AVL_Tree<Key, FileType> tree;  


tree strom2; 
strom2 = (dirName);
```

у меня в узлах не сохраняется `dirName`
а если я напишу так:

```
tree strom2 = (dirName);
```

то сохраняется.

Можете подсказать в чем причина, и как это решить?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Давайте разберём оба варианта и чем они отличаются.
Здесь у Вас вызывается конструктор, полученный объект сохраняется в переменную:

```
tree strom2 = (dirName);
```

А здесь Вы сначала создаёте переменную без явного указания значения — вызывается конструктор по умолчанию (которого нет, но здесь это не играет роли).

```
tree strom2;
```

Потом, как я понял, создаётся новый объект по конструктору с параметром. И он присваивается той переменной. Так как объект передаётся по значению, а не по ссылке, вызывается оператор присваивания, которого также Вы не определили:

```
strom2 = (dirName);
```

Отсюда решение: перегрузите `assignment operator`.

**UPD.** Вы почти правильно написали объявление оператора приставания, нужно ещё дополнить параметрами шаблона. В нём самом предлагаю Вам вызывать *конструктор копирования*:

```
/// Assignment operator.
AVL_Tree<Key,mapped_type,Compare>& operator=(const AVL_Tree<Key,mapped_type,Compare> &oth) {
    // на всякий случай
    if (this == &oth)
        return *this;
    return AVL_Tree<Key,mapped_type,Compare>(oth);
}

/// Copy constructor.
AVL_Tree(AVL_Tree const &oth) {
    // здесь копируйте нужные данные
    this->abc = oth.abc;
}
```

---

`tree strom2 = new tree(dirName);` никак не подойдёт, потому что `new` возвращает *указатель* на созданный объект, у Вас же тип переменной не указатель. Да и в принципе, когда нет нужды, указатели не стоит использовать, чтобы не забыть очистить память.

---

**UPD2.**

Я проверил код, также получил не совсем желаемый результат. В общем, можно обойтись без конструктора копирования. Так как оператор присваивания не статический, нам нужно работать со значениями текущего объекта. А возвращается значение-ссылка на него же самого для возможности подобной записи: a = b = c;

```
AVL_Tree<Key,mapped_type,Compare>& operator=(const AVL_Tree<Key,mapped_type,Compare> &oth) {
    if (this == &oth)
        return *this;
    // копирование данных
    this->abc = oth.abc;
    return *this;
}
```

Comment: Я правильно понял, нужно прописать оператор `AVL_Tree& operator= (const AVL_Tree& other)` в дереве? а потом передать все переменные other  в левую часть? Но тогда что делать с указателями? они у меня используются для постройки корня и его детей.

Comment: Да, с копированием необходимых данных.

Comment: копированием ссылок или созданием новых обьектов с такими же значениями? и еще вопрос, что желательнее, использовать `tree strom2 = (dirName);` или `tree strom2 = new tree(dirName);`

Comment: @Demolver сейчас дополню ответ.

Comment: @Demolver взгляните.

Comment: `return EnhancedSafeArray<T>(oth);` компилятор ругается на неизвестное Т и EnhancedSafeArray

Comment: @Demolver да, извиняюсь, я копировал код из одного своего проекта. Поправил.

Comment: спасибо большое, и последний мини вопрос, в копи конструкторе, когда я копирую `this->root=oth.root;`  получается, что  я просто копирую ссылку, а не создаю новый обьект, это же не критично?

Comment: @Demolver увы, Вы не любите приводить весь нужный код, поэтому не знаю, какого типа root. Кажется, это указатель на другой элемент. Здесь надо смотреть, кто заведует этим объектом, удаляет его из памяти. И надо подумать, должен ли новый объект иметь точно такую же ссылку? В Вашем случае, думаю, так и должно быть, ведь корень у узлов должен быть одним объектом.

Comment: root  у меня ссылка типа Tree_  которая создается при инсерте. А изначально в конструкторе обновляется с помощью nullptr. У меня проблема, при изменении кода, и добавлении оператора и копи конструктора, `strom=dirName;` вообше пустое получается, хотя в копи конструкторе все копируется.

Comment: @Demolver проверил. Вы правы, я вновь исправил код. Много исправлений, но я тоже учусь на ошибках...